# Is it possible to "transform" a histogram into a density plot in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I just figured out that there is the `pgfplots` package with the `hist` feature, that allows to "draw" histograms based on an external data table. 
What I'm looking for is a possibility to transform a histogram into density plot, where instead of counts I have densities according to breaks.
It is like the `hist` function in R (if anybody knows) with parameters `freq = FALSE`.

Or, is there any other way (package) to plot density from the data set in LaTeX?

Answer (score 18):

(Update: This feature is now included in the [unstable version](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) of pgfplots and will become part of the next regular release). That feature is not available in `pgfplots` by default. It's not too complicated to add, however. I've written a patch that makes it possible to use `hist=density` and `hist={cumulative,density}` to create density histograms. This example uses a datafile containing a sample of 2000 points taken from a normal distribution with mean 2 and standard deviation 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    small,
    every axis plot post/.style={
        fill=orange!75,
        draw=orange!50!black
    },
    trim axis left
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,title=\texttt{hist}]
\addplot [hist] table [y index=0] {random.tsv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, title=\texttt{hist=density}]
\addplot [hist=density] table [y index=0] {random.tsv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, title=\texttt{hist=cumulative}]
\addplot [hist=cumulative] table [y index=0] {random.tsv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, title=\texttt{hist=\{cumulative,density\}}]
\addplot [hist={cumulative,density}] table [y index=0] {random.tsv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here's an attempt to recreate the result of the `R` command `random<-rnorm(2000,2,1); hist(random,freq=F)`. The code for the `pgfplots` graph is

```
\begin{axis}[width=8cm,height=4.5cm, axis lines*=left]
\addplot [hist={density,bins=15,data min=-1.5,data max=6}] table [y index=0] {random.tsv};
\end{axis}
```

[image][image]

---

If you just want to try out the feature, you can put the following code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
\pgfplotsset{
    hist/density/.is if=pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density,
    hist/density/.default=true,
    hist/density=false
}
\def\pgfplotsplothandlersurveyend@hist@{%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract@{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@datamax}{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@datamin}%
    \let\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@range=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatdivide@{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@range}{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@N}%
    \let\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@h=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatreciprocal@{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@h}%
    \let\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@invh=\pgfmathresult
    %
    \pgfplotsarraynewempty{pgfp@hist}%
    \pgfplotsarrayresize{pgfp@hist}{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@Nfixed}%
    \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
        \pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to{0}%
    }%
    %
    \pgfplotsapplistXlet\pgfplots@hist@data=\pgfp@hist@@
    \pgfplotsapplistXnewempty\pgfp@hist@@
    \expandafter\pgfplotsplothandlersurveyend@hist@loop\pgfplots@hist@data\pgfplots@EOI
    \let\pgfplots@hist@data=\relax
    %

    % Calculate total count
    \c@pgf@counta=0
    \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by\pgfplots@hist@count\relax  
        \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
    }%
    \edef\pgfp@hist@totalcount{\the\c@pgf@counta}
    \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative
        \c@pgf@counta=0
        \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
            \advance\c@pgf@counta by\pgfplots@hist@count\relax
            \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
            \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
                \pgfmathdivide{\the\c@pgf@counta}{\pgfp@hist@totalcount}%
                \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
            \else
                \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
            \fi
        }%
    \fi%
    %
    %% Density histogram
    % Divide count in each bin by (totalcount*range/bins)
    \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
        \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative
        \else
            \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
                \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
                \pgfmathdivide{\pgfplots@hist@count}{\pgfp@hist@totalcount}
                \pgfmathdivide{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@h}         
                \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
            }%
        \fi
    \fi
    %
    %% End density histogram
    \pgfplots@curplot@threedimfalse
    %
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/hist/handler}%
    \pgfplotsresetplothandler
    \tikz@plot@handler
    %
    \pgfplotsplothandlersurveystart
    %
    \let\pgfplots@current@point@z=\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
        \pgfplotsplothandlerhistgetintervalstartfor\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex
        \pgfplotsplothandlerhist@invtrafo
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@x\pgfmathresult%
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@y\pgfplots@hist@count%
%\message{Survey point (\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y)^^J}%
        \pgfplotsplothandlersurveypoint
    }%
    \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@intervals
        % replicate last count.
        \let\pgfmathresult\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@datamax%
        \pgfplotsplothandlerhist@invtrafo
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@x\pgfmathresult%
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@y\pgfplots@hist@count%
%\message{Survey point (\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y)^^J}%
        \pgfplotsplothandlersurveypoint
    \fi
    %
    \pgfplotsplothandlersurveyend
}
\makeatother
```

---

Here's the patch. If you save it to a file called `density.patch`, you can apply it by navigating to your `pgfplots` directory (on my machine, that's `~/.texlive2011/texmf-local/tex/generic/pgfplots`) and calling `patch < density.patch`.

```
--- pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex       2012-05-01 21:47:37.000000000 +0200
+++ pgfplotsplothandlerswithdensity.code.tex    2012-05-02 12:44:19.927248104 +0200
@@ -1380,6 +1380,7 @@

 \newif\ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@intervals
 \newif\ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative
+\newif\ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
 \pgfplotsset{
    hist/.code={%
        \let\tikz@plot@handler=\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram
@@ -1398,6 +1399,9 @@
    hist/intervals=true,
    hist/cumulative/.is if=pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative,
    hist/cumulative/.default=true,
+   hist/density/.is if=pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density,
+   hist/density/.default=true,
+   hist/density=false,
    hist/handler/.style={/tikz/ybar interval},
    hist/symbolic coords/.style={%
        /pgfplots/symbolic coords={hist/data}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J},
@@ -1521,15 +1525,43 @@
    \expandafter\pgfplotsplothandlersurveyend@hist@loop\pgfplots@hist@data\pgfplots@EOI
    \let\pgfplots@hist@data=\relax
    %
+   
+   % Calculate total count
+   \c@pgf@counta=0
+   \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
+       \advance\c@pgf@counta by\pgfplots@hist@count\relax  
+       \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
+   }%
+   \edef\pgfp@hist@totalcount{\the\c@pgf@counta}
    \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative
        \c@pgf@counta=0
        \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
            \advance\c@pgf@counta by\pgfplots@hist@count\relax
            \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
-           \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
+           \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
+               \pgfmathdivide{\the\c@pgf@counta}{\pgfp@hist@totalcount}%
+               \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
+           \else
+               \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
+           \fi
        }%
+   \fi%
+   %
+   %% Density histogram
+   % Divide count in each bin by (totalcount*range/bins)
+   \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@density
+       \ifpgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@cumulative
+       \else
+           \pgfplotsarrayforeachungrouped{pgfp@hist}\as\pgfplots@hist@count{%
+               \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfplotsarrayset{\pgfplotsarrayforeachindex}\of{pgfp@hist}\to}%
+               \pgfmathdivide{\pgfplots@hist@count}{\pgfp@hist@totalcount}
+               \pgfmathdivide{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfplotsplothandlerhistogram@h}         
+               \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
+           }%
+       \fi
    \fi
    %
+   %% End density histogram
    \pgfplots@curplot@threedimfalse
    %
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/hist/handler}%
```

Comment: +1 Just great! You wrote 'not too complicated' :). I am just using this feature.