# Plot histogram and add already fitted density function

Tags: pgfplots

I want to combine a histogram with a probability density function. Following the advise of Jake

- [drawing a histogram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153325/how-to-compute-an-histogram-plot-bars-binning-the-values-from-a-csv-using-tex)
- [drawing a gamma density function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120441/plot-the-probability-density-function-of-the-gamma-distribution)

My plan now is to combine the two in one plot, like the following from an R example by [Cai](http://www.r-bloggers.com/exploratory-data-analysis-combining-histograms-and-density-plots-to-examine-the-distribution-of-the-ozone-pollution-data-from-new-york-in-r/) or the [one by Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r): 
[image: example]

I don't need to fit the distribution, I already extracted the estimates using [EasyFit](http://www.mathwave.com/easyfit-distribution-fitting.html). I only want to draw a histogram together with the fitted function `gamma(1.7435, 21.263)`.

I read the [`gnuplot` example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160854/how-to-draw-density-estimate-on-histogram-by-pgfplots), again from Jake, but couldn't figure out if this is the only solution. Especially if I have the function already.

Can you help me out?

**MWE** - What I have so far:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ybar,
        ymin=0
        ]
        \addplot +[hist] table [y index=0, col sep=comma,row sep=newline] {
            data
            48
            51
            48
            51
            66
            0
            0
            25
            31
            60
            9
            43
            49
            15
            22
            1
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption[subfigcapskip = 50pt]{Histogram}
        \label{fig:histogram}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={gamma(\z)=
            2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
        declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
        ]

        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        ]
        \addplot [smooth, domain=0:66, red] {gammapdf(x,1.7435, 21.263)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}       
        \subcaption[subfigcapskip = 50pt]{Plot}
        \label{fig:plot}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit - Final Solution**, thanks to Enthusiastic Student!

[image: solution]

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)= 2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);},
    declare function={cauchypdf(\x,\mu,\gamma) = 1/(pi*\gamma*(1+((\x-\mu)/\gamma)^2));}
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    ylabel=Histogram,
    every axis y label/.style={rotate=90, blue, at={(-0.15,0.5)},},
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    yticklabel style={blue}
    ]

    \addplot +[hist] table [y index=0, col sep=comma,row sep=newline] {
        data
        48
        51
        48
        51
        66
        0
        0
        25
        31
        60
        9
        43
        49
        15
        22
        1
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
    ylabel style={black}, 
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none,
    ylabel=PDF's,
    every axis y label/.style={rotate=-90, black, at={(1.15,0.5)},},
    /pgfplots/every y tick scale label/.style={
        at={(1,1)},
        above right,
        inner sep=0pt,
        yshift=0.3em,
    },
    yticklabel style={black},
    legend entries={
        $\textbf{Gamma}~\alpha=1.7435~ \beta=21.263$,
        $~\textbf{Cauchy}~\sigma=16.1340~ \mu=39.554$
    },
    legend style={at={(1,-0.15)}},
    ymin=0,
    ]

    \addplot [thick, smooth, domain=0:66, black, mark=square] {gammapdf(x,1.7435, 21.263)};
    \addplot [thick, smooth, domain=0:66, red, mark=triangle] {cauchypdf(x,39.554, 16.134)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How should the y-axis labels be? Because the value of the gamma function is about a hundred times smaller than the histogram and when you plot them both together, the plotted function will disappear.

Comment: Hm .. good question. I would say it has to be normed. Sadly I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I am just working on it and will post some answer.

Comment: You can justify center your legend by having this code: `legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north},`

Comment: I asked this question based on this question of yours. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211519/combined-legend-for-a-pgfplots-layered-style-plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
            data
            48
            51
            48
            51
            66
            0
            0
            25
            31
            60
            9
            43
            49
            15
            22
            1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={gamma(\z)=
            2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
        declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);},
        ]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=left,
        ylabel=Histogram,
        every axis y label/.style={rotate=90, blue, at={(-0.15,0.5)},},
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
yticklabel style={blue}
        ]
        \addplot +[hist] table [y index=0, col sep=comma,row sep=newline] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
        ylabel style={red}, 
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        ylabel=Function Plot,
        every axis y label/.style={rotate=-90, red, at={(1.15,0.5)},},
/pgfplots/every y tick scale label/.style={
    at={(1,1)},above right,inner sep=0pt,yshift=0.3em},
yticklabel style={red}
        ]
        \addplot [smooth, domain=0:66, red] {gammapdf(x,1.7435, 21.263)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really, really, really nice! I can even add more pdf's to compare them. Thank you!

Comment: @lony I edited to show the y labels.

Comment: @lony If you are printing your plots in black and white, I recommend you to add some legends to the plot and use the line styles too.